# Redirect an instruction to crontab -e

Tags: bash, cron

I want to redirect this command(`* * * * * test.sh`) to the `cronetab -e` but the terminal give me this message of error: `bash: crontab: cannot overwrite existing file`.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Show output of `echo $-`.

Comment: @Cyrus this is the output ```himBCHs```

Comment: `bash: crontab: cannot overwrite existing file` ; just a guess may be `append` using `>>` and probably you are doing `>` .. there is of course nothing in the question at all

Comment: `crontab -e` means you want to edit the crontab interactively, so you'd need to put editor commands into it. Normally, I think you'd do `crontab -l` directed to a temporary file, append your line and then install the modified one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C` in `$-` means that `noclobber` is enabled in your `bash`. Disable it with `set +o noclobber` to be able to overwrite files.

Comment: I did that but the output of ```echo $-``` is the same and i can't redirect the command again

Comment: I solved this with```  (crontab -l >/dev/null; echo "PATH") | crontab -```